# Replace LIKE by SUBSTR

Tags: sql

I tried to select the name of students that end with 'a'. I wrote this code:

```
Select name form students where name like '%a' ;
```

How can I get the same results using `SUBSTR`?

Comment: Please update your question tagging the database you are using (mysql, sql server, oracle, postgres, etc..) as implementations of a substring function are different for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SUBSTR()`.

```
SELECT name 
FROM students 
WHERE SUBSTR(name , -1) = 'a'
```

Comment: Allow for data entered in all caps: `WHERE SUBSTR(upper(name) , -1) = 'A'`. Of course instead of UPPER use whatever function your RDBMS supports.

Answer (score 5):

I actually think using `RIGHT()` would make the most sense here:

```
SELECT name
FROM students
WHERE RIGHT(name, 1) = 'a'
```

The above query would work on MySQL, SQL Server, and Postgres, but not Oracle, where you would have to use `SUBSTR()`:

```
SELECT name
FROM students
WHERE SUBSTR(name , -1) = 'a'
```

Comment: Given that the question has no database tag, I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
Select name from students where SUBSTR(name, -1, 1) = 'a' ;
```

Comment: Typo - FROM not form

Answer (score 1):

Not all platforms accept negative start integers or length integers for SUBSTR()

Can you try if your DBMS supports the RIGHT() string function?

Works like this:

```
SQL>SELECT RIGHT('abcd',1) AS rightmost_char;
rightmost_char
--------------
d
```

Happy playing ...

Marco